# Calibration Resolution

Tags: statistics, sampling, data-analysis, error-propagation, experimental-mathematics

I have a flow meter that I calibrate by doing timed catches. The best resolution I have on my scale is down to 0.01 lb. The meter I'm comparing against goes to 0.001 lb. Usually, I'll have something that flows about 20 lb/hr and I'll do a 5 minute catch on it.

This got me thinking - is there a way to mathematically decide what the minimum catch time would need to be for a good calibration based on the resolutions and flow rate? If someone could show me the math, that'd be extremely helpful, but at least knowing some equations or theory to search on my own would also help.

Comment: Happy to help, but what is catching and what does it have to do with calibration?

Comment: Sorry, here's what I meant: I'll start "catching" liquid that flows through the meter in a bucket and start a timer. After 5 mins, I'll stop my catch and weigh the bucket. If the meter was reading 20 lb/hr (or 1.67 lb per 5 mins) and I actually caught 1.54 lb, then I'll have to rescale my meter to have it calibrated, then do another to confirm. But is 5 mins time enough? And if I caught liquid for 2 hrs, that would give a better representation, but I probably don't need to catch that long. With my scale/meter resolution and aiming to be +-0.5%, is there a  minimum time I should catch liquid?